# Timestamp a Variable being returned

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am a little slow when it comes to jQuery as I am trying to get some footing in this language. I am currently working with FaceAPI and I have it working beautifully. During the recognize phase I have a Ajax call that returns an array of info.

```
$.ajax({
                 url: 'http://api.face.com/faces/recognize.json?&uids=all&namespace=camera_app&detector=Aggressive&',
                 data: formdata,
                 cache: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                 dataType:"json",
                 type: 'POST',
                 success: function (data) {
                     photo = data.photos[0];
                     handleResult(photo)
                 },
```

But what I am most interested in is the "UIDs" that are called the API matches a person's face to their UID. What I want to know is once a UID is returned can a timestamp be placed and saved to my Database that I have setup? [Sidenote: Users photos are only submitted to the API, I do not save them on my database. Only thing I am saving is the users first/last name and UID.] I just don't know how the timestamp function would work with a returning variable.

I want to be able to pull up at a later date the UID and timestamp matching when that information was returned.

Update:

Here is where the UID and Accuracy (confidence) is displayed to the user:

```
function handleResult(photo) {
    console.log(photo)
    var s = "<h2 class='results'>Account Information:</h2>";
    if(photo.tags.length) {
      var tag = photo.tags[0].uids[0];
      s += "<p>";
     //$('#result') .html ('Welcome Back:' + photo.uid + ',' + 'Confidence:' + photo.confidence);
     if(tag.uid) s += "<li> User:" + tag.uid + "</li>";
     if(tag.uid) s += "<li> Accuracy:" + tag.confidence + "%" + "</li>";
     if(tag.uid == 0) s += "I got something, but the data wasn't clear. Sorry.";
      } else {
        s += "<p>Sorry, I didn't find any faces.</p>";
      }
      $("#result").html(s);
```

At this stage I would like a timestamp to be created.

SOLVED:

```
function handleResult(photo) {
    console.log(photo)
    var s = "<h2 class='results'>Account Information:</h2>";
    var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var day = new Date().getDate();
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    var min = new Date().getMinutes();
    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
    }
    if (min < 10)
    min = "0" + min

    if(photo.tags.length) {
      var tag = photo.tags[0].uids[0];
      s += "<p>";
     //$('#result') .html ('Welcome Back:' + photo.uid + ',' + 'Confidence:' + photo.confidence);
     if(tag.uid) s += "<li> User:" + tag.uid + "</li>";
     if(tag.uid) s += "<li> Accuracy:" + tag.confidence + "%" + "</li>";
     if(tag.uid) s += "<li> Timestamp:" + month + "/" + day + "&nbsp;" +  hours + ":" + min + suffix + "</li>";
     if(tag.uid == 0) s += "I got something, but the data wasn't clear. Sorry.";

      } else {
        s += "<p>Sorry, I didn't find any faces.</p>";
      }
      $("#result").html(s);
```

Comment: what does entering timestamp in your DB have to do with ajax call to 3rd party API?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is have the time when the uid is returned from FaceAPI during the recognize call above.

Comment: just use javascript date object to create one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a timestamp in your `handleResult` callback using the Date function.

```
var timestamp = Math.round( new Date().getTime() / 1000 )
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get standard date/time instead of unix?

Comment: You should Google the javascript Date function. It has a lot of handy features which allow you to get days, minutes, years, etc.